# Can I say "I am self-conscious about my eyes"?

Tags: compounds, redundancy

1. "I am self-conscious about my eyes"

sounds like it points to the person speaking twice, therefore making the word "self" redundant. The correct statement to me seems to be

2. "I am self-conscious because of my eyes" or
3. "I am conscious about my eyes."

Is sentence 1 correct?

Answer (score 3):

*self-conscious* is somewhat different from *conscious*.

Check [self-conscious](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/self-conscious):

> *adjective*
>   a) conscious or, esp., unduly conscious of oneself as an object of notice   ⇒ "a self-conscious poet"
>   b) awkward or embarrassed in the presence of others; ill at ease
>   c) indicating embarrassment   ⇒ "a self-conscious cough"

Key descriptive terms are *awkward*, *embarrassed* and *unduly conscious*.

In 1. and 2., *about* and *because of* mean the same thing. You could also use *concerning* or *regarding* in similar contexts.

*about* as used here is the following definition of [***about***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/about):

> 16) on the subject of; concerning   ⇒ "a book about ships"

It is just saying *my eyes* is the topic.

Comment: that eliminate sentence 3 then. My question still remains, comparing sentence 1 and 2.

Comment: Please check my edits.

Comment: Sentence 3 is technically 'correct' in that it doesn't break any grammar rules, but it doesn't make very much sense.

Comment: @user3169 if I am to use the meaning "unduly conscious of oneself" that would make sentence one incorrect since it would translate to "I am unduly conscious of myself about my eyes". Sentence 2 would fit in as "I am unduly conscious of myself because of my eyes". This is where my argument lies, in that the first statement points to the speaker twice.

Comment: To be "conscious" of oneself just means you are "aware" of yourself. No good or bad feelings are involved.

Answer (score -1):

Both 1 and 2 are grammatically correct, but what are you trying to say? If you are trying to say:

- I think about my eyes

then use the first one, but if you are trying to say:

- I think about myself because of my eyes

then the second one seems more accurate. So, which you use is up to you!